# Setting DBI LongReadLen in dbicdump

Tags: perl, dbi, dbix-class

I'm trying to dump my Oracle schema but unfortunately hit with the `ORA-24345` error. From my reading it looks like I need to set the `LongReadLen` option on the database handle.

However, I cannot find the way to set this parameter in `dbicdump`. Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You set that parameter in [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epythian/DBD-Oracle-1.74/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm#LongReadLen)

> ## LongReadLen
>
> The maximum size of long or longraw columns to retrieve. If one of these columns is longer than LongReadLen then either a data truncation error will be raised (LongTrunkOk is false) or the column will be silently truncated (LongTruncOk is true).
>
> DBI currently defaults this to 80.

Answer (score 0):

DBD::Oracle doesn't seem to take handle attributes as arguments to `connect`, which makes this a little bit difficult, but luckily DBIC and dbicdump have a way to work around it. Run dbicdump like this:

```
dbicdump <options> dbi:Oracle:blah username password \
'{ on_connect_do => sub { shift->_dbh->{LongReadLen} = 123456 }'
```

dbicdump recognizes if an extra parameter (after the DSN, username, and password) looks like a perl data structure or subroutine and runs it through `eval` if so, and DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI has [on_connect_do](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#on_connect_do) which can run either SQL or arbitrary code against the handle whenever a connection is made. In this case we can use it to set the LongReadLen attr to whatever value you want.

If you are using the 1-arg version of dbicdump to get options from a config file, you're probably out of luck, unless your loader is `Config::Any::Perl`, in which case you can specify the sub the same way, via the `connect_info`/`options`/`on_connect_do` key.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. I even used with `LongTruncOk`. Both did not take effect:
`dbicdump -o dump_directory=./lib -o components='["InflateColumn::DateTime"]' -o debug=1  My::Schema -o preserve_case=1 'dbi:Oracle:mydbhost/mydbsid' user password '{ on_connect_do => sub { shift->_dbh->{LongTruncOk} = 1 }'`  
Am i missing anything?